# onStateChange not being fired in safari or firefox

Tags: youtube, safari, youtube-api

My site that uses the youtube javascript API broke today. My code is dependent on the callback onStateChange, which currently isn't firing in Safari and Firefox (haven't tested IE). It IS currently working in Chrome.

You can see this directly on the youtube site, look at the events that are being logged:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Anyone know a workaround? Am I correct to assume this is on youtube's end?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to work with the AS3 type, but not iFrame type